# DatagridRow IsSelected not totally working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm currently on the design of my application (WPF), and I'm trying to change the design of the `IsSelected` of `DatagridRow`.

The XAML :

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundSelectedRow}"/>
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundSelectedRow}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This code is working when I've the focus on my application, but when I click out of the view with the `DataGrid`, I lose the Foreground (it takes another color) but the Background is still up with the same...

I don't understand how just one can work, but not the other... Someone knows why ?

**EDIT 1 :**

I don't have any DataGrid.Resources. I set all my style in the App.xaml with this :

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" TargetType="DataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
    <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False"/>
</Style>
```

And I bind it to my DataGrid

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collects}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DGHeaderMargin}"/>
```

Comment: Can you add also `DataGrid.Resources`?

Comment: Try setting the `Foreground` using `Animation` .

Comment: What's `Animation` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change TargedType to `DataGridCell` instead `DataGridRow` (WPF 4.0)

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="dg:DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundSelectedRow}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundSelectedRow}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

solution 2

```
    <DataGrid.Resources> 
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow"> 
            <Style.Resources> 
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>                                  
            </Style.Resources> 
        </Style> 
   </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: It's not really the good answer, because I need to apply the background to the DataGridRow. But the fact to set the Foreground to the DataGridCell is what I needed, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to M. Wiśnicki, I figured out !

If you want to have a properly design, you have to apply style on `DataGridRow` and `DataGridCell`, like this :

```
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundSelectedRow}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundSelectedRow}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

I hope it will help some others developers :)